# Get Data From Another Application's Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, android-youtube-api, android-service-binding

Youtube App allows to [play a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#createPlayVideoIntent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) by its video id. But I need the inverse of that I need the video id that plays on Youtube App.

I checked [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android#youtube-android-player-api) but I couldn't find any way to do this.

I checked [Android Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) to interact with the Youtube App. As far as I understand [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) can bind service with an Activity but this activity must be in the same application.

[MusixMatch](https://youtu.be/4616oIm1lLo) can access Youtube Video information but I don't have any idea to do that.

How can I get Youtube video info from another application?

Comment: you need to add intent-filter in your manifest for receiving data through intent from another app .when you share a video from youtube that link contains the videoId

Comment: @Danialclarc I can catch video id in that way. But I need to catch it without any user event like sharing it. As MusixMatch does.

Comment: I think MusixMatch is using google voice recognition keyboard